# C++ pointer increment

Tags: c, pointers, math, increment

Please help me understand how the value of q is initially 1 and later changes to 0.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{    
    int i=10;
    int *p, *q;
    p = &i;
    printf("%u\n%u\n%u\n",p,q,*q);
    *q++=*p++;
    printf("%u\n%u\n%u\n%u",p,q,*p,*q);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1527896876
1527897120
1
1527896880
1527897124
1527897124
0
```

Comment: Looks like C. Are you sure you are writing in C++?

Comment: The value of `q` is indeterminate because it is used without initialization. Also you invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`: `%u` expects `unsigned int`, but you are passing `int*` for some of them.

Comment: This code is liable to crash. The first `printf()` is dereferencing an uninitalized pointer, which causes _undefined behavior_.

Comment: For printing pointers, use the `%p` format specifier.

Comment: The output on my machine is a termination on the first `printf`, due to **undefined behavior**.  (Termination is not guaranteed, but is one of an infinite number of possibilities due to **undefined behavior**, and is considerably more pleasant than [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> int *p, *q;
> p = &i;
> printf("%u\n%u\n%u\n",p,q,*q);
> ```

`int*` is a wrong type for the format specifier %u. If you pass an argument of wrong type, then the behaviour of your program is undefined.

---

> ```
> printf("%u\n%u\n%u\n",p,q,*q);
> *q++=*p++;
> ```

Here, `q` has an indeterminate value. It doesn't point to any object. You indirect through the pointer to access an object that it points to. Which is a contradiction because it doesn't point to any object.

Indirecting through an indeterminate pointer results in undefined behaviour.

---

The behaviour of your program is undefined. That explains everything about the behaviour of the program.

Answer (score -1):

I think what happens is that here

```cpp
*q++=*p++;
```

the post-increment operator of q is executed after the assignment.
So, you basically set the value of q to p, and then you increment it.
Also, i don't think the increment operator of p does anything.

For a better understanding look at the following example

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int i = 10;
  int *p;
  int *q = new int[2];
  q[0] = 9;
  q[1] = 99;
  p = &i;
  printf("%u\n", *q);
  *q++ = *p++;
  printf("%u\n", *q);
  printf("%u", *--q);
  return 0;
}
```

```
9
99
10
```

Notice how, in the end q points to the next element, thanks to the post-increment operator.

Anyway, i have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: The code has Undefined Behavior because `q` is used unintialized

Comment: Yes, but the question was why does the value change between printfs.

Comment: and the explanation for this behavior is that the program has Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Undefined Behavior means that the program doesn't have a defined behavior, i.e. it can be anything: it can crash, it can print `Hello World`, it can print `1 0`, it can print `0 1`, it can hang or basically ANY behavior.

Comment: Yes, but unless the value is changed by another program between the two printfs (highly unlikely) it should be the same.

Comment: https://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: Is there something specific you want me to see? because i am not disagreeing with you about undefined behavior. Look at my example, which does initialize the values and illustrates what i mean.

Comment: @daskalgg `it should be the same` Such assumptions as this cannot be relied on when the behaviour of the program is undefined. It could be the same. It could be something else. The program could summon demons from your nose.